# How to find rows with duplicate values that exist across JSON arrays

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working with a table defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE objects(
  id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY,
  identifiers     JSONB
);
```

The `identifiers` column contains a JSONB document in the following form:

```
{
  "primary_id":   "7b5d5137-12cb-430c-9181-094900c2b512",
  "secondary_id": "u7wKxfGAAFHwTj20"
  "tertiary_ids": [
    "75",
    "15",
    "0E"
  ]
}
```

Where the length of the `tertiary_ids` array can vary from row to row, and any or all of the ids may not exist in some rows. For example:

```
{
  "primary_id":   "7b5d5137-12cb-430c-9181-094900c2b512",
  "tertiary_ids": [
    "75",
    "15",
    "0E"
  ]
}
```

or:

```
{
  "primary_id":   "7b5d5137-12cb-430c-9181-094900c2b512",
  "secondary_id": "u7wKxfGAAFHwTj20"
}
```

I want to find all the rows where any or all of the ids are duplicated across rows. For example:

```
{
  "primary_id":   "7b5d5137-12cb-430c-9181-094900c2b512",
  "secondary_id": "u7wKxfGAAFHwTj20"
  "tertiary_ids": [
    "75",
    "15",
    "0E"
  ]
}
```

would match

```
{
  "primary_id": "669c91a3-3693-465e-a8f9-39a3350350f5",
  "secondary_id": "CyXu5rDJCh6H1h0o",
  "tertiary_ids": [
    "4A",
    "0E"
  ]
}
```

and

```
{
  "secondary_id": "u7wKxfGAAFHwTj20"
}
```

The part that has me stumped is the array. Without the array, I've been able to find duplicates via the following:

```
SELECT
  identifiers->>'primary_id'   AS primary_id,
  identifiers->>'secondary_id' AS secondary_id,
  id
FROM objects
WHERE
  identifiers->>'primary_id' IN (
    SELECT identifiers->>'primary_id' FROM objects
      GROUP BY identifiers->>'primary_id'
        HAVING COUNT(identifiers->>'primary_id') > 1
  )
  OR
  identifiers->>'secondary_id' IN (
    SELECT identifiers->>'secondary_id' FROM objects
      GROUP BY identifiers->>'secondary_id'
        HAVING COUNT(identifiers->>'secondary_id') > 1
  )
ORDER BY
  identifiers->>'primary_id',
  identifiers->>'secondary_id',
DESC;
```

In my efforts to include the array, I've tried different variations of the following, to no avail:

```
SELECT
  identifiers->>'primary_id'   AS primary_id,
  identifiers->>'secondary_id' AS secondary_id,
  jsonb_array_elements_text(identifiers->'tertiary_ids') AS tertiary_ids,
  id
FROM objects
WHERE
  identifiers->>'primary_id' IN (
    SELECT identifiers->>'primary_id' FROM objects
      GROUP BY identifiers->>'primary_id'
        HAVING COUNT(identifiers->>'primary_id') > 1
  )
  OR
  identifiers->>'secondary_id' IN (
    SELECT identifiers->>'secondary_id' FROM objects
      GROUP BY identifiers->>'secondary_id'
        HAVING COUNT(identifiers->>'secondary_id') > 1
  )
  OR
  EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM jsonb_array_elements(identifiers->'tertiary_ids') AS t(tertiary_ids)
    GROUP BY t.tertiary_ids HAVING COUNT(t.tertiary_ids) > 1
  )
ORDER BY
  identifiers->>'primary_id',
  identifiers->>'secondary_id',
DESC;
```

While this does indeed find duplicates in `primary_id` and `secondary_id`, rows that only have duplicates in one or more `tertiary_ids` are not detected.

To focus on the issue, I've simplified the query to:

```
SELECT
  jsonb_array_elements_text(identifiers->'tertiary_ids') AS tertiary_ids,
  id
FROM objects
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM jsonb_array_elements(identifiers->'tertiary_ids') AS t(tertiary_ids)
    GROUP BY t.tertiary_ids HAVING COUNT(t.tertiary_ids) > 1
  );
```

Which doesn't return any rows, even though duplicates across the arrays do exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the query you are looking for:

I compare each record with the other records in the table, and if at least one of the primary_id, secondary_id or any of the elements in tertiary_ids matches it, I return it with the result.

```
SELECT *
FROM objects o1
WHERE exists (SELECT 1
             FROM objects o2
             WHERE o1.id != o2.id 
                   AND (o1.identifiers->>'primary_id' = o2.identifiers->>'primary_id' 
                   OR o1.identifiers->>'secondary_id' = o2.identifiers->>'secondary_id' 
                   OR (o1.identifiers->>'tertiary_ids')::jsonb ?| ARRAY(SELECT value
                                                                        FROM jsonb_array_elements_text((o2.identifiers->>'tertiary_ids')::jsonb))));
```

This query allows you to check what are the duplicate records for each record:

```
SELECT o1.id, array_agg(o2.id) AS ids_duplicated
FROM objects o1
INNER JOIN objects o2 ON o1.id != o2.id 
                      AND (o1.identifiers->>'primary_id' = o2.identifiers->>'primary_id' 
                      OR o1.identifiers->>'secondary_id' = o2.identifiers->>'secondary_id' 
                      OR (o1.identifiers->>'tertiary_ids')::jsonb ?| ARRAY(SELECT value
                                                                           FROM jsonb_array_elements_text((o2.identifiers->>'tertiary_ids')::jsonb)))
GROUP BY o1.id    
ORDER BY o1.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with an acceptable solution, at least for the simplified case - searching for duplicate values across `tertiary_ids` arrays:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    *, jsonb_array_elements_text(identifiers->'tertiary_ids') AS tertiary_id
  FROM objects
) t
WHERE
  id IN (
    SELECT id FROM (
      SELECT
        id,
        jsonb_array_elements_text(identifiers->'tertiary_ids') AS tertiary_id
      FROM objects
    ) mac_t
    WHERE
      tertiary_id IN (
        SELECT tertiary_id FROM (
          SELECT
            jsonb_array_elements_text(identifiers->'tertiary_ids') AS tertiary_id
          FROM objects
        ) mac_t_t
        GROUP BY tertiary_id HAVING COUNT(tertiary_id) > 1
      )
  )
ORDER BY tertiary_id;
```

The only issue I have with this solution, is that it will return duplicate rows - one for each duplicate found in a given array.